# replace alt+f4 with ctrl+w

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I am using this [**Remap <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>**](https://github.com/Drugoy/Autohotkey-scripts-.ahk/blob/master/Remap%20ALT%2BF4%20to%20CTRL%2BW/Remap%20ALT%2BF4%20to%20CTRL%2BW.ahk) script but it does not work on some programs, such as *evernote*.

I tried to create one myself:

```
^w::
SetTitleMatchMode 2
IfWinExist Evernote
    Send !{F4}
else
return
```

but it still does not work

Any suggestions on how to replace <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd> with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> in evernote?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include the settitlematchmode inside the script, but place it above it. Also the Else statement doesn't do anything, but most importantly, your ifwinexist ONLY checks to see if you have a window open (does not need to be the active window) with Evernote in the title.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
Return ; To prevent this script from running on startup of the script

^w::
IfWinActive, Evernote
    Send, !{F4}
Return
```